# How is deciding a problem not equivalent to finding a valid certificate for verification?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Take a decision problem $Q$, which maps encoded instances of a problem, i.e., $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace \ast$ to the solution set $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$.
Since $Q$ is in $NP$, there exists a verification algorithm $A$, which takes an input and a certificate, in that order, as arguments and maps those to $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$, depending on whether there exists a certificate proving that the solution to the input is $1$.

If this presentation of what a verification algorithm does is correct, then it is unclear to me if, for a binary-encoded problem instance $x$,

$$Q(x) = 1 \iff \exists y (A(x, y) = 1).$$

It seems to me that *if* there is a certificate, this means that the decision for that input is affirmative, so that in theory, you could attach sufficient information to a certificate such that it characterizes a solution to the decision problem, iterate through the entire set of certificates and, once you have found one that satisfies $A(x, y) = 1$, you have also found a solution to the problem for the respective input.

Maybe someone could explain to me if that equivalency above is wrong and if so, why. I know the difference between a problem and the verification part, but then again, on some level I do not.
Neither am I sure about anything else, so feel free to point out mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the following excerpt:

> iterate through the entire set of certificates

There might be many possible certificates. For example, a SAT instance on $n$ variables has $2^n$ certificates. Iterating through all of them would take exponential time. Although processing each takes only polynomial time, processing all would take exponential time. This is the difference between verification and decision.

Your argument does show that if a problem is in nondeterministic time $T(n)$, then it is in deterministic time $\exp T(n)$. For example, $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{EXP}$.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clearing that up. So otherwise, my argument is correct, including the equivalency part? Sorry for sounding incredulous, I was just really convinced I went wrong there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really understand the rest of your argument.

Comment: Then let me rephrase a little: my algorithms book proves that the circuit satisfiability problem is NP-complete. To prove that every problem in $NP$ is reducible to circuit-SAT, a characteristic of NP-completeness, it restates what a reduction algorithm tries to achieve at all. It reads "Given an input $x$, it must compute a circuit $C = f(x)$ that is satisfiable if and only if there exists a certificate $y$ such that $A(x, y) = 1$. $f$ is the reduction function computed by the reduction algorithm here.

Comment: (cont.) Now, if I were to substitute the "there exists a certificate $y$ such that $A(x, y) = 1$" part by "$CIRCUIT-SAT(x) = 1$" would this still make sense? $CIRCUIT-SAT$ is the decision problem here. I am trying to understand if this simpler notion, that the input $x$ satisfies $CIRCUIT-SAT$, is the same as that there is *some* certificate $y$ that satisfies the verification algorithm for that same input. If it's still too blurry, I will incorporate this into my question and expand a little more.

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.

Comment: All right, thanks a lot. Allow me to ask one more thing, please: if iterating through all certificates would be feasible in polynomial time, would that imply P = NP? The verification algorithm runs in polynomial time and polynomial times polynomial is polynomial, correct? So any problem in NP could be solved in polynomial time by just trying the verification algorithm for every certificate.

Comment: It's not feasible. This is why NP-hard problems are hard.

Comment: @cadaniluk If I understand correctly, what takes polynomial time is processing _one_ certificate, but what you're asking about is processing _all_ certificates, which is the part that would take exponential time to accomplish, making it unfeasible.